# changing ckeditor toolbar config does not affect in dolibarr ERP

Tags: ckeditor, dolibarr

As you know Dolibarr is a great ERP system written in PHP and MySQL.

It uses CKeditor as text editor. 
Now I want add some options to it's toolbar.

There is a `dolibarr_details` defined in `htdocs\theme\eldy\ckeditor\config.js` (like Below) that used in Products card page. But when I add new options to that has not any affect on show editor toolbar.

```
config.toolbar_dolibarr_details =
    [
        ['Source','Maximize'],
        ['SpellChecker', 'Scayt'],      // 'Cut','Copy','Paste','-', are useless, can be done with right click, even on smarpthone
        ['Format','Font','FontSize'],
        ['Bold','Italic','Underline','Strike','-','TextColor','RemoveFormat'],  // ,'Subscript','Superscript' useless
        ['NumberedList','BulletedList','Outdent','Indent'],
        ['JustifyLeft','JustifyCenter','JustifyRight','JustifyBlock'],
        ['Link','Unlink','SpecialChar']
    ];
```

I do not know why this has no effect?

If anyone knows this, please help me.

Comment: I thought php developers that have experience work with Dolibarr can help

Comment: The tags are about the technologies directly relevant to the issue/question. Since the issue and the question doesn't have anything to do with PHP, you shouldn't add that tag.

Comment: From CKEditor point of view I can only say if you are using `config.toolbar_dolibarr_details = [...` you should also use `config.toolbar = 'dolibarr_details';`. Please see: https://docs.ckeditor.com/ckeditor4/docs/#!/api/CKEDITOR.config-cfg-toolbar.

Answer (score 0):

as i see  in my dolibarr install

```
config.toolbar_dolibarr_details =
    [
        ['Source','Maximize'],
        ['Cut','Copy','Paste','-','SpellChecker', 'Scayt'],
        ['Format','Font','FontSize'],
        ['Bold','Italic','Underline','Strike','Subscript','Superscript','-','TextColor','RemoveFormat'],
        ['NumberedList','BulletedList','Outdent','Indent'],
        ['JustifyLeft','JustifyCenter','JustifyRight','JustifyBlock'],
        ['Link','Unlink','SpecialChar']
    ];
```

is related only for ckeditor in product lines in invoices,propsals,orders ..

Comment: In This case how can I change (add or remove some buttons in toolbar) in editors shown in product card ?

Comment: please check the line 191 of doleditor.class.php in  this directory                                                                  htdocs\core\class\doleditor.class.php